# How do I properly level convert between microcontroller and 3.3 V SPI pins?

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, integrated-circuit, spi, pullup

I am trying to create a PCB that interfaces a type-K thermocouple with a microcontroller (STM32F303K8) using KiCad 5.0.0.

I previously sent the PCB design out for fabrication, but now I'm noticing problems with my design which I overlooked, because I guess I misinterpreted what logic-level conversion was (this being the first time I came across it).

I wrongly assumed that if I supplied 3.3 V to the digital and analog inputs of the MAX31856 I would not need to convert levels. Now I see that I do need that for the SPI lines.

What I need help on specifically is the circuitry used to convert the levels. I have seen in my book that you can just use a voltage divider, but the diagram I am using uses switching diodes and pull-up resistors (pulled to 3.3 V from the onboard MIC5225-3.3 regulator) on CS, MOSI, and SCK, but not on the SDO.

[image: Adafruit Breakout Board - MAX31856]
<sup>Image from [Adafruit](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-max31856-thermocouple-amplifier.pdf).</sup>

I'm assuming the diodes are acting as some sort of level shifter, however, I'm not entirely sure. Can someone explain the purpose of the diodes? Also, due to blurriness, I cannot tell the value of the three pull-up resistors. They look like 1 kΩ, but I have been reading around and have seen "10K" suggested. *Edit: I looked at the physical board and saw 1002, meaning 10 kΩ, please ignore that the pullup resistors are 1 kΩ in my diagram, I have changed them to 10 kΩ now.*

This is my circuit version 2 at the moment:

[image: Version 2 of my circuit based on the above picture]

Here is my original circuit, which I believe is not correct anymore:

[image: V1 of my circuit diagram]

Here is the corrected circuit diagram thanks to each of the comments:

[image: Correct circuit with I2C bidirectional level shifting and removed SPI diodes and pullup resistors]

Simulation result confirming the shifting circuitry performs as expected:

**(5 V to 3.3 V)**

[image: LTSpice Schematic]
[image: Simulation Result 5v to 3V3]

**(3.3 V to 5 V)**
(Not enough rep to post 8 or more links, so I can't show schematic modification.)
The pulse was put onto the 3.3 V line, and Von was reduced to 3.3 V giving 5 V on the 5 V line.

[image: 3v3 to 5V result]

Comment: You shouldn't be using pull ups on the spi lines, or diodes for that matter. You do need the pull ups on the i2c lines though.

Comment: The microcontroller on the Nucleo board runs on 3.3V, and it looks like the thermometer chip uses a 3.3V VDD -- what leads you to believe that you need level shifting on SPI?  It *does* look like you might need level shifting on the I2C bus, though.

Comment: @RonBeyer I believe the I2C LCD has onboard pullup resistors. I've used this LCD with same microcontroller for a previous project and didn't use any pullups. Do you know why diodes, and pullups have been used on adafruit's diagram?

Comment: Depending on the diode, it may be a "poor man's" voltage converter, emphasis on poor. Careful selection of the dose would have to happen as to not distort the signal and it would limit speeds depending on the characteristics. In general don't use pull ups or diodes there.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thank you, I have read about this, but it's hard to find a definitive answer with all the variation in answers online about when/when not pullups, etc are needed. I will remove the diodes, and resistors and put it back like had it before.

Comment: @TimWescott Oh, maybe a have a poor memory of it, but I was sure it was 5V. I thought I needed level shift purely due to example circuits I had seen online. I haven't made that many pcbs.

Comment: Re: blurry Adafruit schematics, all Adafruit images come in different resolutions. When you click at thumbnail you are taken to [download page](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/35946) where you can select perfectly readable "original" resolution.

Answer (score 1):

> I wrongly assumed that If I supplied to MAX31856 3V3 to the digital
>   and analogue inputs of the chip then why would I need to level
>   convert? Now I see that I need that for SPI lines.

You absolutely do NOT need that for SPI lines, since both STM32 and MAX31856 work at 3.3V.

> I'm assuming the diodes are acting as some sort of level shifter
>   however I'm not entirely sure. Can someone explain the purpose of the
>   diodes.

Diodes *in combination* with pull-up resistors work as uni-directional level shifters on Adafruit board, basically imitating open-collector operation of I2C bus and making it compatible with 3.3~5V MCUs. Again, you do not need this.

The operation itself is very simple. When MCU outputs 0 the diode opens and pulls MAX31856 input down to 0. When MCU outputs anything higher than 3.3V the diode closes and allows pull-up resistor to supply 3.3V ("1") to input pin. It does not allow 5V output from 5V MCU pass through to MAX31856. Note that this severely reduces the maximum possible data rate of the SPI communication due to relatively weak 10k pull-ups reducing slew of the rising edge.

Comment: Thank you regarding the blurry schematic solution and further confirmation regarding not needing the diodes/resistors on the SPI lines. I didn't originally think I did, it went against all the (limited) prior knowledge of SPI I had.

Comment: Hi, I believe I need a bidirectional level shifter for 5V lcd to the 3v3 stm32. Can you let me know if this looks correct. https://i.imgur.com/HxB8e00.png

Comment: @RiccardoFrancescoGeraci There is no LCD on the linked image. But yes, you do need bidirectional level shifter for I2C _if there are 5V pull-ups on LCD **or** if LCD is not compatible with 3.3V I2C bus_. Otherwise you can simply use your own pull-ups to 3.3V. If you want to put level shifter on your board you can use Sparkfun schematics for [BOB-12009](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009), but you only need 2 circuits out of their 4.

Comment: @RiccardoFrancescoGeraci The new image seems to be correct. You finally got it right, congratulations! Instead of adding links in the comments you should embed the image into original question, where everybody can see and comment

Comment: The LCD is the center-most symbol. I made the symbol and footprint myself so it may not be instantly identifiable as an LCD with I2C backpack. I think there is 5v pull ups on the LCD but I cannot say for sure, I cannot follow the circuit as the black soldermask makes them impossible to see. Some of these lcds say input voltage 3v/5v, but i bought my so long ago I have no idea the specs. Yeah thats' the schematic I had used, the sparkfun ones you linked.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I've done something right. I had no idea about level shifting before this project. Hi, I linked in the comment because wasn't sure if you see/be notified about the image. I'll do that now.

Answer (score -3):

Use a bi-directional level translator which converts 5V to 3.3V. Its easy to  use without any changes in software or hardware.

This company makes such level translators:

[www.maximintegrated.com/](http://www.maximintegrated.com/)

Comment: Connecting a 3.3V chip to 3.3V MCU does not need a level shifter of any kind, and this sounds like an advertisement as you link to main page of a company. Please at least try to read a bit comments and other answers before posting an answer, as no level conversion is needed.

Comment: The question clearly said level translation between 5V to 3.3V . The question was changed. Technology uses copyrighted products and it is nearly impossible to write or design anything using theoretical block diagrams. Therefore I posted a link of level translators.

Comment: No, question never asked how to level convert between 5V and 3.3V. It simply asks how to properly level shift between 3.3V SPI and MCU, and since MCU is already 3.3V, the proper way is to not level shift at all. This is also said in comments from 2020 already.

Comment: The question explicitly asked how to shift 5V to 3.3V. Look at circuit diagram which indicates (5 V to 3.3 V). The author  (or somebody else)  changed the question. You seem mistaken.  Something is amiss in the way the question was followed up.. If you still disagree, I can delete the answer.

Comment: If the focus switched from not needing SPI translation to needing I2C translation, it is also not needed. Those IO pins used for I2C on the MCU are 5V tolerant.